# Tensorflow "logits and labels must be broadcastable" and not able to fit, how to solve it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I a new to machine learning, I tried to create a CNN model that identifes clouds. The full problem and templates I followed can be found here:https://www.kaggle.com/code/thitinan/template.  This is my code

```
`import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2 
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.python.keras import layers, models#datasets
import seaborn as sns
from skimage.io import imread
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Dropout, Input, Flatten, MaxPool2D
from keras.utils import to_categorical
from keras.optimizers import Adam # Define the optimizer
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os


adam = Adam(learning_rate=0.01)

train_data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/owenc/Desktop/WeatherIdentify/input/cloud-type-classification2/train.csv')
checkpoint_path = "C:\\Users\\owenc\\Desktop\\WeatherIdentify\\codes\\cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)
'''
(training_images, training_labels), (testing_images, testing_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()
training_images_testing_images = testing_images/1024, testing_images / 1024
'''
#class_names = ['cirriform clouds', 'high cumuliform clouds', 'stratocumulus clouds', 'cumulus clouds', 'cumulonimbus clouds', 'stratiform clouds', 'clear sky']

cases_count = train_data['label'].value_counts()
num_class = 7



# Training data generator
def data_gen(data, batch_size):
    # Get total number of samples in the data
    n = len(data)
    steps = n//batch_size
    
    # Define two numpy arrays for containing batch data and labels
    batch_data = np.zeros((batch_size, 224, 224, 3), dtype=np.float32)
    batch_labels = np.zeros((batch_size,num_class), dtype=np.float32)

    # Get a numpy array of all the indices of the input data
    indices = np.arange(n)
    
    # Initialize a counter
    i =0
    while True:
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
        # Get the next batch 
        count = 0
        next_batch = indices[(i*batch_size):(i+1)*batch_size]
        for j, idx in enumerate(next_batch):
            img_name = data.iloc[idx]['id']
            label = data.iloc[idx]['label']
            
            # one hot encoding
            encoded_label = to_categorical(label, num_classes=num_class)
            # read the image and resize
            img = cv2.imread(f"C:\\Users\\owenc\\Desktop\\WeatherIdentify\\input\\cloud-type-classification2\\images\\train\\{str(img_name)}")
            img = cv2.resize(img, (224,224))
            
            # normalize the image pixels
            orig_img = img.astype(np.float32)/255.
            
            batch_data[count] = orig_img
            batch_labels[count] = encoded_label
            
        i+=1
        yield batch_data, batch_labels
            
        if i>=steps:
            i=0


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(input_shape=(224,224,3),filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64,kernel_size=(3,3),padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=(3,3), padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=4096,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=4096,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation="softmax"))
model.build()
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=adam)

epochs = 50
batch_size = 10
train_data_gen = data_gen(data=train_data, batch_size=batch_size)
hist = model.fit(train_data_gen,
                epochs = epochs,
                steps_per_epoch=100 // batch_size,callbacks=[cp_callback])
model.save('model','C:\\Users\\owenc\\Desktop\\WeatherIdentify\\models')

#plot
plt.plot(hist.history["acc"])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_acc'])
plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
plt.title("model accuracy")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.legend(["Accuracy","Validation Accuracy","loss","Validation Loss"])
plt.show()
'''
it might seem crappy because I am a newbie. When I run it comes upwith this:
```

Epoch 1/50
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\owenc\Desktop\WeatherIdentify\codes\main.py", line 111, in 
hist = model.fit(train_data_gen,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' defined at (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\owenc\Desktop\WeatherIdentify\codes\main.py", line 111, in 
hist = model.fit(train_data_gen,
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
return fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1742, in fit
tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1338, in train_function
return step_function(self, iterator)
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1322, in step_function
outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1303, in run_step
outputs = model.train_step(data)
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1081, in train_step
loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\training.py", line 1139, in compute_loss
return self.compiled_loss(
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in **call**
loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 142, in **call**
losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 268, in call
return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\losses.py", line 2122, in categorical_crossentropy
File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\backend.py", line 5566, in categorical_crossentropy
return tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits'
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[10,2] labels_size=[10,7]         [[{{node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_3933]

Im also new to stack overflow so sorry for the bad organization. The code usd to work without the plotting and under a small CNN model that has only few layers.

I tried to change .fit to .fit_generator (line 111) but it still didnt work. Alo tried to delete the plotting part and also didnt work.

Comment: Try to include error messages in code blocks with syntax highlighting